# Help identifying 4-pin PWM fan connector

Tags: pwm, connector, fan, gpu

Does anybody know the name/type of the connector shown below? Context: it is 4-pin PWM fan connector for the fan of an Nvidia RTX A6000.

Dimensions: 5mm x 1mm x 4mm, 1mm pitch

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image: Photo 3]

=== Edit ===

Thanks to @EnricoMigliore's answer: the Molex Pico-EZmate OTS 36920 can be adapted to fit the fan connector on the RTX A6000 PCB. I just had to remove the tiny plastic edges as shown in the last photo below.

[image: Photo 4]

Comment: Please honor Enrico by "accepting" his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That connector looks like Molex's Pico-EZmate or Pico-EZmate Plus.

Beware of the fact that many far east connectors manufacturers just copy and slightly modify Molex's connector.

They actually infringe patents and don't label their connector in order not to be recognized and sued.

Comment: _Molex's Pico-EZmate or Pico-EZmate Plus_. The EZmate  has a 1.2 mm pitch, which is what OP's measurements indicate, so that's a better bet. The Pico-EZmate Plus has a pitch of 1 mm, so I don't this that's it. However, neither one has a metal clasp, so these are not Molex connectors.

Comment: I indeed wrote "it looks like".

Comment: You did, yes, and I saw it. I was just trying to add to what you said. Sorry if it came across as contradicting you. That was not my intent.

Comment: No problems at all Davide.

Comment: @EnricoMigliore, indeed, Pico EZmate fits with a small modification. I got the Pico-EZmate OTS 36920 (https://sg.element14.com/molex/36920-0400/cable-assy-4pos-wtb-rcpt-rcpt/dp/3257268) and I had to cut the plastic edges highlighted in the last photo of my edited question (they seem to be less than 1 mm, however, they need to be removed).

Comment: Great! As I told you, some anonymous manufacturers copy connectors made by big names' manufacturers.